# mailto does not work in browsers

Tags: html, mailto

The following is an output from PHP/jquerymobile. When I test it on Mac and set the default browser to FF, FF opens a lot of tabs and frozes. In Chrome, it opens gmail but there is no cc.
I am hoping someone can suggest how to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="gear" id="submit" href="mailto:(parent)?subject=
Design homework&cc=teacher1@myschool.com,teacher2@myschool.com,teacher3@myschool.
com &body=Dear parents,%0D%0D I am writing my ... meeting.%0D%0D ...%0D%0D 
Thank you,%0D%0D John Doe" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" 
data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn 
ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-b">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
<span class="ui-btn-text">Ready to GO! Click Me.</span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear ui-icon-shadow"/>
</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the default email handler in your Firefox is... Firefox. In happened to me once with PDF documents, Firefox was opening new tabs until crashing.

Go to Preferences > Applications and check that the `mailto` Content-Type is properly configured.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="gear" id="submit" href="mailto:(parent)?subject=
Design homework&cc=teacher1@myschool.com,teacher2@myschool.com,teacher3@myschool.
com &body=Dear parents,%0D%0D I am writing my ... meeting.%0D%0D ...%0D%0D 
Thank you,%0D%0D John Doe" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" 
data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn 
ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-b">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
<span class="ui-btn-text">Ready to GO! Click Me.</span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear ui-icon-shadow"/>
</span>
</a>
```

Insert a normal Email Adress instead of (parent).